# JavaScript Vairable Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, mongoose

This is the html file and it's not much important

```
<body>
        <!-- Select Radio Button -->
        <label for="radio1">Select</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1"  >
        <!-- Multi-Select Radio Button -->
        <label for="radio2"  >Multi-Select</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio2" >
        <br>
        <!-- Items -->
        <label for="radio2">Item 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="item" id="item0" value="item1">
        <label for="radio2">Item 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="item" id="item1"  value="item2">
        <label for="radio2">Item 3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="item" id="item2" value="item3">
        <label for="radio2">Item 4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="item" id="item3" value="item4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn " onclick="handling_dbs()">Submit</button>
</body>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

Now here's the index.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/pro',{useNewUrlParser:true}); 
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'connection error'))
var selectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    selection_type : {type:String, required:true},
    selected : {type:String, required:true}
})

                                        

var selections =  mongoose.model('selection',selectionSchema);
console.log(selections)  //Added this to check what's inside the selections variable

function handling_dbs(){ 
     console.log(selections) //Added this to check what's inside the selections variable
    if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked){
        let length=4;
        for(let i=0;i<length;i++){
            if(document.getElementById(`item${i}`).checked){
                let selected_item = document.getElementById(`item${i}`).value;
            }
        }
        
        let doc = new selections({
            selection_type:'Select',
            selected:   `${selected_item}`
        });
        doc.save();
        console.log('Yes')
    }
}
```

Now when I try to access it inside the function it's undefined, when I have clearly defined it.
Why can't I access it inside the function, when it's clearly a global variable.

Comment: Which variable is undefined? And in which function - presumably within `handling_dbs`?

Comment: selections variable

Comment: And what does the console reveal? Remember not everyone has used Mongoose - could it be asynchronous?

Comment: It reveals what's inside it outside the function

Answer (score -1):

I think mongoose.connect is an async function, so the value of "mongoose.model('selection',selectionSchema);" is not available yet, when you assign it to the selections constant.
Moving the initialization of the selections constant into the handling_dbs() function should resolve the issue.
A more sophisticated solution would be waiting till the db connection is set up, and only make the click listener work after that.